# recursive insertion sort method giving StackOverflowError

Tags: java, recursion, stack-overflow, insertion-sort

I am trying to analyze the Insertion Sort recursive method in Java for different arrays of size n. It sorts fine for small array sizes, but when I try to test it for let's say an array size of 32000, it gives me a StackOverflowError.

Is there a way to resolve this? I am using eclipse IDE.

The recursive algorithm I am using is below:

```
    ...

    @Override
    public int[] recursiveSort(int[] list)
    {
        // Start the clock
        this.startTime = System.nanoTime();

        count = 0;

        int n = list.length;

        insertionSortRecursive(list, n);

        // Stop the clock
        this.stopTime = System.nanoTime();

        return list;
    }

     // Recursive function to sort an array using insertion sort
    static void insertionSortRecursive(int arr[], int n)
    {
        count++;

        // Base case
        if (n <= 1)
            return;

        // Sort first n-1 elements
        insertionSortRecursive( arr, n - 1 );

        // Insert last element at its correct position in sorted array.
        int last = arr[n - 1];
        int j = n - 2;

        // Move elements of arr[0..i-1], that are greater than key, to one position ahead of their current position.
        while (j >= 0 && arr[j] > last)
        {
            count++;
            arr[j + 1] = arr[j];
            j--;
        }
        arr[j + 1] = last;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your insertion sort implementation. It's just memory issue while keeping track of stack call. You can just quickly go through this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/214741/what-is-a-stackoverflowerror) for more details. Even though, we can update some of JVM parameter to increase stack memory (refer [here](https://blogs.oracle.com/saas-fusion-app-performance/how-to-set-stack-size-to-overcome-javalangstackoverflowerror)), but eventually this issue will happen for some other size (e.g. 64k, 128k, etc). So I would recommend you to change to normal iterative implementation instead of recursion.